# Cannot add anything to a ThreadPool

Tags: c#

I am trying to use `ThreadPool`, but it is giving me errors:

```
class test
{
    public void testMethod1(bool param)
    {
        var something = !param;
    }

    public void testMethod2()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(testMethod1), true); //expected a 'void testMethod1(object) signature'
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(testMethod1(true))); //method name is expected
    }
}
```

How to properly use `ThreadPool`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [WaitCallback delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects a `System.Object` as it's argument.  You would need to use that to pass in the value.

```
private void TestMethodWrapper(object param)
{
   TestMethod1((bool)param);
}

public void TestMethod1(bool param)
{
    var something = !param;
}

public void testMethod2()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(TestMethodWrapper), true);
}
```

This was the common pattern early on, but the current C# language allows more flexibility.  For example, using a lambda is far simpler:

```
public void testMethod2()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => testMethod1(true));
}
```

When calling using this last method, the compiler effectively creates the wrapper method for you.

Comment: Clear enough. ;) Thank you!

Comment: @ojek On a side note, if you're using .NET 4 or 4.5, I'd recommend using `Task`/`Task<T>` instead of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` - they both provide huge advantages...

Answer (score 2):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => testMethod1(true));
```